# How to implement Task Scheduler Manager on C#?

Tags: c#

I want to write a `Scheduler Manager`.
My `Scheduler Manager` must contain 3 types of running tasks

```
 - Each XX seconds ( ex. each 15 seconds )  
 - Every day at same time ( ex. every day at 7 a.m )  
 - Emergency task - this is task that UI can add and will run imitatively
```

My problem, is that I don't know how to implement the alarm, that will popup at the time of the task.

I can calculate the time between 'now' and the target time, using `Timer.Interval` - that will wait for the right time to popup the task.

Is there better way to implement this?

Comment: Why not use the pre-installed task scheduler on windows? Or a scheduling library? If you're doing this just for learning purposes, you should investigate a bunch of options (even if they all fail) and post your attempts here.

Comment: this need to be inner project task - and i can't use OS  task scheduler

Comment: Where is the code of your attempts / results of your findings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would [Quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/features.html) work?  You can setup jobs to run on certain intervals as described above.